# .NET EF contextfactory share over libarary

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have my project where I have `MyDbContext` class with dbsets etc. And I have a library project where I have some utilities shared over my projects.

I would like use `MyDbContext` in the library, too. But for every project the `dbcontext` is logically another. I wanted do it over interface where will be property `IDbContextFactory`. But this interface needs generic type (`DbContext`) but it doesn't exist in the library.

I tried to find some solution but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your advice.

[Edit]

This is in my application

```
public partial class TestRepository 
{
   public TestRepository(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> con) 
   {

   }
}
```

And i would be use something like this in library. But i cannot use there MyDbContext because there isn't exists. So i hope i will do it with interface where was reference to IDbContextFactory but i need generic type...

```
// Not working in library
public partial class TestRepository 
{
   public TestRepository(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> con) 
   {

   }
}
// Maybe work but i dont how do it
public partial class TestRepository 
{
   public TestRepository(IFrameworkDbContextFactory con) 
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what your utilities do or need to do? Depending on what the utilities need to do may change how you go about solving your dilemma

Comment: @amura.cxg i tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you.

In library crete interface

```
public interface ISharedDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<DbContext> {}
```

In project impement it

```
public class SharedDbContextFactory : ISharedDbContextFactory {
   private IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _contextFactory;

   public SharedDbContextFactory(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> contextFactory) {
       _contextFactory = contxtFactory;
   }

   public MyDbContext CreateDbContext()
   {
       return _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
   }
}
```

And then add it to di configuration. You can also register to di only IDbContextFactory and use it. I think it's better to have your custom interface.

I hope I gave you some advice and didn't say anything wrong. Someone can correct me.